# How to filter a list via specific positioning of variable letters

Tags: python

What would be the most pythonic way of filtering a list using variables in exact positions of a word/list?

e.g. If my list is `[HELLO, JELLO, JUUNO, ELNOO]`, how would I filter the list for any word containing 'EL' in a specific position of the word but exclude words which do not have the correct positioning of the letters? So if I was to filter for 'EL' in position 2 and 3 of a word I would want it to output `[HELLO, JELLO]` but exclude `[ELNOO]`

```
wordlist = ['HELLO', 'JELLO', 'JUUNO', 'ELNOO']

#flter wordlist for 'EL'in position 2 and 3
#filter wordlist for starting with 'J' and ending with 'O'
varA = 'E'
varB = 'l'
varC = 'J'
varD = 'O'
```

I thought about importing re and using `re.search`, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you can use regex. search for `re`

Comment: I said that in the last line of the post!

Comment: so as @match wrote only if you know the words and need something very specific

Comment: I was trying to give the most simple version of the problem, essentially I have made a hangman engine that guesses 5 letter words (1 of 12500) and each time it guesses a letter I want it to filter the list to remove words based on the exact positioning of right/wrong guesses. Would you say re would be the best for this? Currently I filter words containing right or wrong guesses, which is obviously a lot less efficient.

Comment: use index() for strings https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_index.asp

Comment: I was using this project to learn Python, I wish I knew about index function at the start, I use a long-winded multi-nested loop in order to calculate the frequency of each letter in the list, I could have just used index. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 3):

For a simple fixed string like this, a slice comparison is probably easiest:

```
words = ['HELLO', 'JELLO', 'JUUNO', 'ELNOO']
[x for x in words if x[1:3] == 'EL']
```

Answer (score 1):

extending @match's answer if you need it as a function

```
words = ['HELLO', 'JELLO', 'JUUNO', 'ELNOO']

filter_word = lambda wordlist, keyword, pos1, pos2: [x for x in wordlist if x[pos1-1:pos2] == keyword]
filtered_words = filter_word(words, "EL", 2, 3)
print(filtered_words)
```

Comment: filter is a keyword

Comment: @Ido yeah my bad correcgted

Comment: It worked with 'filter =' but not with 'filtered_word ='
But this is a really cool answer, will have a play about with it to try understand it!